# handle a function expecting different input and output which is mocked using EasyMock

Tags: unit-testing, junit, easymock

the function im testing calls the function findByNames via different inputs and expects different output. I need to mock it as it using service uDao. So should i write two different expects? But its not working... how should i handle this scenario?

```
  EasyMock.expect(uDao.findByNames(CollectionUtils.newArrayList(target1Username)))
                .andReturn(CollectionUtils.newArrayList(target1Group)).once();
 //code in between
 EasyMock.expect(uDao.findByNames(CollectionUtils.newArrayList(target1Username, ownerUsername)))
         .andReturn(CollectionUtils.newArrayList(target1Group, ownerGroup));

/*target1Username, ownerUsername are strings and target1Group,
   ownerGroup are of class    UserGroup
*/
```

Comment: May be i could use EasyMock.expect(userGroupDao.findByNames(EasyMock.isA(List.class))).andReturn(CollectionUtils.newArrayList(target1Group, ownerGroup)); But this shows error as findByNames is expecting a Collection<String>

Comment: What do you mean by "But its not working"?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: <failure message="java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call findByNames([elementsuser1@elements.com, owner@owner.com]):
    findByNames([elementsuser1@elements.com, owner@owner.com]): expected: 1, actual: 0" type="junit.framework.AssertionFailedError">junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call findByNames([elementsuser1@elements.com, owner@owner.com]):
    findByNames([elementsuser1@elements.com, owner@owner.com]): expected: 1, actual:0

Comment: I am not understanding what this error is trying to say...

Comment: While debugging i noticed that the 1st pass for findByNames works properly....but for the second expect of findByNames the debugger throws an error and is not even able to go inside function findByNames

Answer (score 0):

Your failure message:

```
<failure message="java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected method call
     findByNames([elementsuser1@elements.com, owner@owner.com]): 
     findByNames([elementsuser1@elements.com, owner@owner.com]): expected: 1, actual: 0"
```

implies that the passed in Collections are not equal.

EasyMock uses object equality to test that the parameters match.  Since you say the first call to `findByNames` works (which uses a `Collection<String>`) and the 2nd call (which uses a `Collection<UserGroup>`) fails, I would guess the problem lies with the `UserGroup` class.

The `toString()` of the Set passed in appear to have the same `toString()` values as expected so either:

1. the `UserGroup.equals()` method checks additional fields that aren't set to equal values or
2. `UserGroup` doesn't define an equals method so the default equality check is used.  The default equals method only says objects are equal if they are the same reference.  So two different instances with the same values will not be equal. or
3. (less likely) the Collection returned by `CollectionUtils.newArrayList()` doesn't implement equals correctly.  I will assume that this method comes from a 3rd party library and is implemented correctly.  I'm just putting this here incase the other 2 scenarios don't fix the problem.

Comment: 2 nd call also takes Collection<String>..the output is Collection<UserGroup>

Comment: Oh, then what is the code for `CollectionUtils.newArrayList()` perhaps that doesn't implement equals correctly?

Comment: public static <T> List<T> newArrayList(final T... items) {
  List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
  list.addAll(Arrays.asList(items));
  return list;
 }

Comment: function newArrayList() in CollectionUtils is as mentioned above